# Refresh mandatory fields on form (red line)

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

Is it possible to refresh form and set mandatory fields (marked with red line) based on other field modification? I tried refresh(), reread(), but red line is not appears. Red line appears only when I clicked on this field.
This is form LedgerJournalTransDimension.

Comment: Can you show your code or provide more details?

Comment: What version of Dynamics do you use?

Comment: Try `formRun.redraw()` after whatever refreshes you're doing.

Comment: Thanks, but formRun.redraw() doesn't help. Maybe I should clear cache on this form? How to clear cache on form? I tried SysGlobalObjectCache::clearAllCaches(), but doesn't help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

element.redraw() after super() in modified() control method is solution

Comment: `element` is the active instance of `formRun`...same thing